# does anybody knows pickle with commandline?

Tags: python, dictionary, cmd, pickle

I am trying to make a dictionary with pickle by using command line but while getting input from command line I am getting "module object has no attribute load " ?

Here's my code:

```
import pickle
import sys
dfile = open ("new.dat","w")
print "get argument"
lifesize=(sys.argv[1])
print "get another argument"
two=sys.argv[2]
print "last argument"
three=sys.argv[3]

z={lifesize:[two,three]}
pickle.dump(z,dfile)
dfile.close()
ifile=open("new.dat")
d1= pickle.load(ifile)
```

and save above as newdocument

cmd:python newdocument.py

I also tried to do a dictionary for every lifesize and save them as new.dat and get them..
need really help .?thank you

Comment: It works for me (on Mac OS X). On windows you might need to append "b", so open(..., "wb") and open(..., "rb").

Comment: @newebi I formatted the code for you by selecting the code and pressing the "{}" button.

Comment: this works also for me, just a note: using cPickle instead of pickle is always better, you can even do `import cPickle as pickle` and use it without modification

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is perfectly fine, please check your version of Python, and possibly update/reinstall.

---

The Python interpreter complains that `pickle.load()` doesn't exist, while it certainly does: http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#pickle.load